# I would like to know how could I use assert to guarantee that all my elements of a list of lists have the same length

Tags: python-3.x, list, assert

I would like to ensure that all my  elements of a list of lists have the same length.

I tried:

```
assert len((map(len,motifs))) == len(motifs[0])
```

Then:

```
assert all(len(m[i]) == len(m[0]) for i, m in enumerate(motifs))
```

Do you have any clean and quick suggestion?

Comment: `m` is the sublist, so `m[i]` and `m[0]` don't make sense - it should be `m` and `motifs[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [...]
length = <Specified length or len(l[0])>
assert all(len(x) == length for x in l)
```

You may use for the `length` parameter any predefined value, or simply you can use the length (using `len`) of any item in your list of list.

Answer (score 2):

```
assert all( [len(item) == len(motifs[0][0]) for sublist in motifs for item in sublist] )
```